# Get selected checkbox value in *ngFor angular 2

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have json as follow:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Parent",
    "submenus": [
        {
            "name":"Child1"
        },
        {
            "name":" Child2"
        },
        {
            "name":" Child3"
        },
        {
            "name":"Child4"
        },
        {
            "name":"Child5"
        }
    ]
  }
]
```

and code in html file

```
 <li *ngFor='let submenu of filterType.submenus'>
         <div class="checkbox">
        <input id="checkbox1" class="styled" type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="submenu.selected">
        <label for="checkbox1">
                         {{submenu.name}}
                    </label>
    </div>

      </li>
```

how to get only those checkbox which are clicked..Please help me out as i hv to pass selected value to angular highchart graph.

Comment: trying to be clear - when you want your checkbox to be checked. As i notice you are using submenu.selected but from your json response you don't have selected property on submenus object.i you hope you got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create some temp json using your submenus

```
   filternames = [
            {
              name: 'Child1',
              checked: false
            },
            {
              name: 'Child2',
              checked: false
            },
            {
              name: 'Child3',
              checked: false
            },
          ];

           checked() {
          return this.filternames .filter(item => { return item.checked; });
        }
```

HTML

```
  <li *ngFor='let submenu of filternames'>
         <div class="checkbox">
        <input id="checkbox1" class="styled" type="checkbox" 
[(ngModel)]="submenu.checked" [value]="submenu.name">
        <label for="checkbox1">
                         {{submenu.name}}
                    </label>
    </div>

      </li>


      <pre>Selected names: <span *ngFor="let filternames of checked()" ">{{ filternames.name}}</span></pre
```

>

checked() function always returns your selected checkbox values

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i found a better solution with passing submenu.name to event and then get this pushed it to an array..Link..             https://plnkr.co/edit/mWtlkydF0FzioS3c2esQ?p=preview

Comment: your solution is excellent if your graph should change based on checkbox selection.

Answer (score 1):

Because you've bound the checkboxes to your model with:

```
[(ngModel)]="submenu.selected"
```

All you have to do is crawl/iterate through `filterType.submenus` and filter for those with `selected===true`

Comment: thanks for your answering, Can you please share piece of code like storing selected checked value in array.. Thank again in advance